# Getting omxplayer to play through a HiFiBerry DAC

Tags: audio, omxplayer, hifiberry

First, I know a thing or two about the Pi, but the audio system is still a complete mystery to me, so please be patient with my ignorance.

After installation of a HiFiBerry DAC, omxplayer does not output sound through the DAC.

Recently, I was using omxplayer to play audio out of the headphone jack. Recognizing I needed higher quality audio for my application, I sprung for a
[HiFiBerry DAC2 Pro XLR](https://www.hifiberry.com/shop/boards/hifiberry-dac2-pro-xlr/). As per the [installation instructions](https://hifiberry.com/docs/software/configuring-linux-3-18-x/), I did the following:

I edited `/boot/config.txt` by commenting out:

```
#dtparam=audio=on
```

In the same boot config file, I configured the device tree overlay file:

```
# for hifiberry DAC2 PRO
dtoverlay=hifiberry-dacplus
```

I creating /etc/asound.conf:

```
pcm.!default {
  type hw card 0
}
ctl.!default {
  type hw card 0
}
```

And then to test, I installed mplayer and tested it successfully.

```
mplayer stereo-test.mp3
```

But when I ran omxplayer on the same file, I did not get output to the HiFiBerry DAC.

How do I have to configure the audio system so omxplayer outputs to the DAC as well, or get more info about what is really going on?